# Can this function be refactored to be O(1)

Tags: performance, function, math, refactoring

I have this function which is used to calculate a value with diminishing returns. It counts how often an ever increasing value can be subtracted from the input value and returns the number of subtractions. It is currently implemented iteratively with an infinite loop:

```
// inputValue is our parameter. It is manipulated in the method body.
// step counts how many subtractions have been performed so far. It is also our returned value.
// loss is the value that is being subtracted from the inputValue at each step. It grows polynomially with each step.
public int calculate(int inputValue) {
    for (int step = 1; true; step++) {// infinite java for-each loop
        int loss = (int) (1 + 0.0006 * step*step + 0.2 * step);
        if (inputValue > loss) {
            inputValue -= loss;
        } else {
            return step;
        }
    }
}
```

This function is used in various places within the larger application and sometimes in performance critical code. I would prefer it to be refactored in a way which does not require the loop anymore.

I am fairly sure that it is possible to somehow calculate the result more directly. But my mathematical skills seem to be insufficient to do this.

Can anybody show me a function which produces identical results without the need for a loop or recursion? It is OK if the refactored code may produce different results for extreme values and corner cases. Negative inputs need not be considered.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could you also provide a typical range of values for the `inputValue` (i.e. not corner cases)?

Comment: Positive integers with between 3 and 10 digits.

Comment: The main difficulty in this problem is the casting to `(int)` in your calculation of `loss`. It is fairly simple to solve the problem if `loss` is an exact floating-point value--just sum over the three terms of the polynomial from `1` on up to get a cubic polynomial, then solve the cubic. But the rounding down to an integer complicates the problem. If you problem is solved for floating-point `loss` would you consider the few resulting errors to be "edge cases"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can make the code faster preserving the exact logic. Particularly you have some hard to emulate rounding at

```
   int loss = (int) (1 + 0.0006 * step*step + 0.2 * step);
```

If this is a requirement of your business logic rather than a bug, I don't think you can do significantly better. On the other hand if what you really want is something like (from the syntax I assumed you use Java):

```
public static int calculate_double(int inputValue) {
    double value = inputValue;
    for (int step = 1; true; step++) {// infinite java for-each loop
        double loss = (1 + 0.0006 * step * step + 0.2 * step); // no rounding!
        if (value > loss) {
            value -= loss;
        } else {
            return step;
        }
    }
}
```

I.e. the same logic but without a rounding at every step, then there are some hopes.

**Note**: unfortunately this rounding does make a difference. For example, according to my test the output of `calculate` and `calculate_double` are slightly different for every `inputValue` in the range of `[4, 46465]` (sometimes even more than by `+1`, for example for `inputValue = 1000` it is `calculate = 90` vs `calculate_double = 88`). For bigger `inputValue` the results are more consistent. For example for the result of `519`/`520` the range of difference is only `[55294, 55547]`. Still for every results there is some range of different results.

First of all, the sum of `loss` in the case of no rounding for a given max `step` (let's call it `n`) has a closed formula:

```
sum(n) = n + 0.0006*n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6 + 0.2*n*(n+1)/2
```

So theoretically finding such `n` so that `sum(n) < inputValue < sum(n+1)` can by done by solving the cubic equation `sum(x) = inputValue` which has a [closed formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients) and then checking values like `floor(x)` and `ceil(x)`. However the math behind this is a bit complicated so I didn't went that route.

Please also note that since `int` has a limited range, theoretically even your implementation of the algorithm is `O(1)` (because it will never take more steps than to compute `calculate(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` which is a constant). So probably what you really want is just a significant speed up.

Unfortunately the coefficients `0.0006` and `0.2` are small enough to make different summands the dominant part of the sum for different `n`. Still you can use binary search for a much better performance:

```
static int sum(int step) {
    // n + 0.2 * n*(n+1)/2  + 0.0006 * n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6
    // ((0.0001*(2n+1) + 0.1) * (n+1) + 1) * n
    double s = ((0.0001 * (2 * step + 1) + 0.1) * (step + 1) + 1) * step;
    return (int) s;
}

static int calc_bin_search2(int inputValue) {
    int left = 0;
    // inputValue / 2 is a safe estimate, the answer for 100 is 27 or 28
    int right = inputValue < 100 ? inputValue : inputValue / 2;

    // for big inputValue reduce right more aggressively before starting the binary search
    if (inputValue > 1000) {
        while (true) {
            int test = right / 8;
            int tv = sum(test);
            if (tv > inputValue)
                right = test;
            else {
                left = test;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // just usual binary search
    while (true) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        int mv = sum(mid);
        if (mv == inputValue)
            return mid;
        else if (mid == left) {
            return mid + 1;
        } else if (mv < inputValue)
            left = mid;
        else
            right = mid;
    }
}
```

**Note**: the `return mid + 1` is the copy of your original logic that returns one `step` after the last `loss` was subtracted.

In my tests this implementation matches the output of `calculate_double` and has roughly the same performance for `inputValue` under `1000`, is x50 faster for values around `1_000_000`, and x200 faster for values around `1_000_000_000`